# Why does Table only replace first instance of iterator?

Tags: list-manipulation

When I write

```
Table[If[x <= q, 0, q], {q, 1, 3}]
```

the output is

```
{If[x <= 1, 0, q], If[x <= 2, 0, q], If[x <= 3, 0, q]}
```

rather than, as I would expect,

```
{If[x <= 1, 0, 1], If[x <= 2, 0, 2], If[x <= 3, 0, 3]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) is not replacing anything - as noted in the documentation, `Table` works similar to [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) in that it temporarily assigns a value to the iterator variable, after which the expression in the body is evaluated. In your case, you are seeing the effects of the [`HoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) attribute of [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html): Since the condition is neither `True` nor `False`, `If` stays unevaluated, which means the second and third argument stay as they are, no value is inserted.

To fix this, you can use e.g. [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject the values into the held parts of the expression:

```
Table[
 With[{q = q},
  If[x <= q, 0, q]
  ],
 {q, 1, 3}
 ]
(* {If[x <= 1, 0, 1], If[x <= 2, 0, 2], If[x <= 3, 0, 3]} *)
```